# Short-term rental application process and security deposit

Tags: real-estate, new-jersey

I was looking for an apartment for 6 months in New Jersey and found one apartment. During our apartment tour, in online data base, or application; they never mentioned about a short term lease fee. However, after a few days of application they gave me a call asking for extra $500. When I tried to withdraw the application before signing the lease, they told me that they will keep the $400 security deposit as liquidated damage which I was aware of. My question is are they supposed to mention the $500 short-term lease fee on their website or application, if they mention about $400 will be charged if we withdraw our application after two days? It is my right to have prior knowledge about the all the fees if I have a $400 withdrawal fees right?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a contract, such as a lease, the party making the offer has to provide all of the terms, so that you can decide if you accept the offer or not. That does impose on you an obligation to read the paperwork and any materials referenced by the lease. When you have accepted the offer (especially after you have handed over money as a deposit), they cannot unilaterally change the offer. Signing the lease is legal proof that you have accepted the contract, but your prior conduct (giving them money) is also proof of acceptance.

They are free to politely (or impolitely) *ask* you to pay them extra money, so you just have to bear in mind that you have no legal obligation to comply with their wish. On the remote chance that you missed something, you could ask there where in the agreement this extra charge is specified.
It is entirely legal to decline their request and to insist on compliance with the original contract terms. You can read [this document](https://proxy.lsnj.org/rcenter/GetPublicDocument/Sites/LAW/Documents/Publications/Manuals/TenantsRights.pdf) on NJ landlord-tenant law. However, if you insist in breaching the lease (as opposed to sticking to your guns about not owing this extra fee), then they *would* be entitled to keep your security deposit.